# iTMSTransporter : How to submit an uploaded in-App purchase for Apple review without iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, submit, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, in-app

I currently use iTMSTransporter (Apple’s command-line tool) for verify and upload
App Store packages (.itmsp) that's contain metadata of a new in-App purchase to the App Store.

but I'm forced to submit this in-App already uploaded for review in iTunes Connect manually before Apple checks!

is there a way to submit in-App purchase for review via iTMSTransporter?

Comment: If an app has not yet been released, new IAPs are created in the Waiting for Review state.

After an app has gone live however, IAPs through iTMSTransporter are created at Ready To Submit state, and it needs just a click to send for review. 
Can't this step be bypassed? :/

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `RMConnector`(See: https://github.com/realmacsoftware/RMConnecter/), it takes all of the hassle out of submitting my .itmsp files to iTC.

Also see their amazingly helpful blog post: http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/mastering-itunes-connect-transporter

Remember, Apple **Doesn't** have official documentation on this as it's an internal tool used by only Xcode; this ultimately leads to no guarantee as to weather or not it will work, **especially** with the constant updates to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks @vborra for this infos but doesn't really answer my problem. Because the new IAPs uploaded with RMConnector will have Ready To Submit state in iTunes Connect. Then it needs a click to send for review. Remember the aim is no manual steep.

Comment: Well, ask your self the following question: If you upload it through Xcode, does it auto submit or do you still have to manually do it? If so, then its impossible to do it from iTMSTransporter, because thats XCODE's internal tool.